# Loop bandwidth for Costas loop

Tags: pll

How do the alpha & beta parameters referenced in [this implementation](https://pysdr.org/content/sync.html#fine-frequency-synchronization) of a software based digital phase locked loop relate to the loop bandwidth, in Hz? The loop filter equations gleaned from the code appear to be:

$$f_n=f_{n−1}+ \beta\epsilon_n \tag 1$$
$$\phi_n = \phi_{n-1} + f_n + \alpha\epsilon_n \tag 2$$

where $f_n$ is the present frequency estimate, $\phi_n$ is the present phase estimate, and $\epsilon_n$ is the present error (multiplication of the real and imaginary components in the Costas loop). [Thanks to @Peter K. for clarification here]

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what these proportional and derivative constants *mean*. Maybe you have some specific loop filter design in mind? We can't know that! Please show the formula, a block diagram, or something else that shows the relationship between the costas loop and these constants.

Comment: Added a block diagram. Does that help? I am referencing this implementation: https://pysdr.org/content/sync.html#fine-frequency-synchronization

Comment: ah Marc's Pysdr! The diagram would help if it was a first-order PID controller architecture, but it's not – and the text also does not mention any proportional and derivative constants. So, I'm not sure where you take these from? Why do they apply to this?

Comment: Proportional and derivative are terms I've seen in a lot of online resources and texts:
1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop - under "Filter" section
2. https://web.ece.ucsb.edu/~long/ece594a/PLL_intro_594a_s05.pdf

I can remove those terms if it's confusing. I'm wondering about the alpha and beta values.

Comment: Your block diagram **does not show** any alpha or beta values.  Presumably these are in embedded in the loop filter, but such things aren't always standard.  You need to show us how _the loop you are implementing_ uses $\alpha$ and $\beta$ -- preferably by _editing your question_ to give us the difference equation or the transfer function of the loop filter.

Comment: @TimWescott - Cleaned up the question. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's a direct relationship.

The effective filtering that is happening looks like:
\begin{align}
f_n &= f_{n-1} + \beta \epsilon_n\\
\phi_n &= \phi_{n-1} + f_n + \alpha \epsilon_n
\end{align}
where $f_n$ is the present frequency estimate, $\phi_n$ is the present phase estimate, and $\epsilon_n$ is the present error (multiplication of the real and imaginary components in the Costas loop).

Just looking at a generic first order system:
$$
x_n = x_{n-1} + \alpha \epsilon_n \leftrightarrow (1-z^{-1})X(z) = \alpha E(z)
$$
so that
$$
\frac{X(z)}{E(z)} = \frac{\alpha}{1 - z^{-1}}
$$

Which, in Matlab, looks like

```
alpha = 0.132
beta = 0.00932

b = alpha;
a = [1 -1];

freqz(b,a, 512, 44100)
```

which shows the following frequency response if your sampling rate is 44.1 kHz.

[image: freqz() output]

Comment: Is the idea to use the frequency response to measure the 3dB loop bandwidth (i.e., 3 dB down from the peak of the response)?

Comment: @BigBrownBear00 : Yes, that could be one way to get a loop bandwidth out of the equations in your linked page (that I've tried to write in my answer).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to clarify my question based on the link provided. I added it to the original question for clarity. Appreciate the help!